# Why can I not apply TailwindCSS values over 10?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm using `tailwindCSS` to build a landing page on a `NextJS` website that I originally made years ago. It used to have some issues with the `JIT` feature, so I decided today that I would update tailwind from V1 to V3 (`3.0.23` specifically).

My problem is, I now cannot apply any stylings above 10! I first was trying it with `top-16`, but it didn't work, so I tried changing it to `mt-16` and still no luck!

The weird thing is, if I change it to either `top-10` or `mt-10`, the element moves as expected.

Similarly, breakpoints have stopped working from `md`.

It's very strange and I've tried a lot of things to fix it. It's confusing because I have the `Tailwind Intellisense` extension for VS Code and it's telling me that these classes exist as well as the Tailwind Docs saying the same! Do any of you have any ideas about what's going wrong?

The code is as follows (I've tried to remove anything that seems irrelevant):

```
<div className="relative h-screen xl:h-auto">
    <video
        ...
        className='opacity-60 object-cover h-full w-full xl:h-auto xl:overflow-hidden'
    >
        ...
    </video>

    // The following line is what I'm trying to move 
    <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 right-0 text-center mx-3 mt-10">
        <div className="relative">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    theme: {
        extend: {},
        colors: {
            blue: { main: '#0182B2' },
            yellow: { main: '#FFD600', panama: '#FFF26B' },
            red: { main: '#CC360A' },
            green: { main: '#5F8B16' },
            white: '#ffffff',
            black: '#000',
        },
    },
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    plugins: [],
};
```

and my `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: ['tailwindcss', 'autoprefixer'],
};
```

I hope somebody can help me to figure this out! I'm just trying to centre some text inside the video!

EDIT: Oh, I'm also using `Typescript` if that raises any flags for anybody!

Please and thank you in advance and I hope you're all having a great day :)

Comment: in the package json what is the version of tailwindcss

Comment: @D4ITON ^3.0.23

Comment: In the docs of tailwindcss there is an example with the nextjs version 10+, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs, the version could be